# Can I determine the Model of phone from code (that is Mozart or Trophy)?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to determine from code the model of phone. For example HTC Mozart or PD67100. Is this info accessible?

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://www.nickharris.net/2010/09/windows-phone-7-how-to-find-the-device-unique-id-windows-live-anonymous-id-and-manufacturer/

Comment: Sorry for my question. It was quite simple, just couldn't find it before. http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/06/windows-phone-7-mango-tutorial-15.html#.TszUCLK4qso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DeviceStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394037%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) class allows access to the name (typically the model) of the device.